# How to create xml file using node js dynamically?

Tags: xml, node.js

```
 vvar readline = require('readline');
 var et = require('elementtree');
 var XML = et.XML;
 var ElementTree = et.ElementTree;
 var element = et.Element;
 var subElement = et.SubElement;
 var fs = require('fs');
 var root;

 var rl = readline.createInterface
   ({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout
    });

 function createXML(root)
  {
    var etree = new ElementTree(root);
    rl.question('\nEnter file name to create xml: \n', function (f){
    var xml = etree.write({'xml_declaration': false});
    console.log(xml);
    var newfile = fs.writeFileSync(f,xml);
    console.log("\nXML file created..!!\n");
   });
 }  

 function runElement(subroot,num1){
    if(num1 > 0)
    {
    rl.question('\nEnter element name: \n', function(name1){
        rl.question('\nEnter element data: \n', function (data)
                {
            var subroot2 = subElement(subroot, name1);
            subroot2.text = data;
            num1 = num1 - 1;
            runElement(subroot,num1);
                });
    });
     }
   else
   {
    createXML(root);
   }
  }

function getSubRootElements(root, numItem)
{
if(numItem > 0){
    rl.question('\nEnter sub root element name: \n', function (name){
        var subroot = subElement(root,name);
        rl.question('\nEnter the number of elements: \n',  function(num1){
            runElement(subroot,num1);
        });
    });
    }
   }

 function start() 
{
      rl.question('\nEnter root element: \n', function(x){
        root = element(x);
        rl.question('\nEnter the number of sub root elements: \n', function(numItem){
        getSubRootElements(root, numItem);
    });
   });
   } 

 start();
```

above one is code for creating xml in node js. I have tried to create multiple subroots and elements but i am not getting where i am stuck. I am giving inputs from the console so cant write functions within the loop. HOw it should be done?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var et = require('elementtree');
var XML = et.XML;
var ElementTree = et.ElementTree;
var element = et.Element;
var subElement = et.SubElement;
var fs = require('fs');
var root;

var rl = readline.createInterface
({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function createXML(root)
{
  var etree = new ElementTree(root);
  rl.question('\nEnter file name to create xml: \n', function (f){
  var xml = etree.write({'xml_declaration': false});
  console.log(xml);
  var newfile = fs.writeFileSync(f,xml);
  console.log("\nXML file created..!!\n");
 });
}  

function getElements(root, subRoot, numSubRoot, numElements)
{
  if(numElements > 0)
  {
    rl.question('\nEnter element name: \n', function(name1)
    {
      rl.question('\nEnter element data: \n', function (data)
      {
        var subroot2 = subElement(subRoot, name1);
        subroot2.text = data;
        numElements = numElements - 1;
        getElements(root, subRoot, numSubRoot, numElements);
      });
    });
  }
  else
  {
    //get the next subroot element
    getSubRootElements(root, numSubRoot)
  }
}

function getSubRootElements(root, numSubRoot)
{
  if(numSubRoot > 0)
  {
    rl.question('\nEnter sub root element name: \n', function (SubRootName)
    {
      var subRoot = subElement(root, SubRootName);
      rl.question('\nEnter the number of elements: \n',  function(numElements)
      {
        numSubRoot = numSubRoot - 1;
        getElements(root, subRoot, numSubRoot, numElements);
      });
    });
  }
  else
  {
    createXML(root);
  }
}

function start() 
{
  rl.question('\nEnter root element: \n', function(x)
  {
    root = element(x);
    rl.question('\nEnter the number of sub root elements: \n', function(numSubRoot)
    {
      getSubRootElements(root, numSubRoot);
    });
  });
} 

start();
```

Comment: How to create new xml using node js, giving input from the console? Is it possible?

Comment: you mean consume the whole xml from the console or individual elements of xml from console?

Comment: Individual elements of xml from console

Comment: You can surely do it. If you are writing an interactive application then you can take the tags and the values from user and create an object.
Once you are done taking inputs, you can convert the object to xml using the xml2js.

Comment: Above i attached node js script that i tried to get create an xml but not possible.

Comment: Is there anyway to give input from the console in node js?

Comment: You can checkout inquirer package.

Comment: without function can i pass arg like rwa_input?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: And can you give me the reason for down voting my answer? Whoever down voted it? I would like to know and improve.

Comment: Is there possible to create multiple elements in subroot? how it possible?

Comment: Above attached script in that i want create multiple elements in sub root but not getting. Where i am going wrong?

Comment: Just like you have created subroot element, create elements under subroot. Can you post a sample xml of your requirement? That would clarify everything and I can help you much better.

Comment: I have edited above script plz check it once. I need create multiple subroots in each subroot multiple element should need be create.

Comment: chaitanya sama u there?

Comment: I'm sorry. I have been a little busy.
I have edited the code snippet.
Try it out.

Comment: It works fine. Thank you..!! For same code how it should be modified like removing child element or add new element?

Comment: You can add more callbacks for new tags of your xml and chain those callbacks in places needed.
You can go through the code that I have given and see the flow. I'm guessing you are fairly new to nodejs and aren't very familiar with callbacks. http://mostafa-samir.github.io/async-iterative-patterns-pt1/
You can check this page. It explains very clearly how to use callbacks in iterations and recursion. That will help you.

Comment: I got the flow how it works but not getting how update will happen and how it should be done?

Comment: Chaitanya Sama, i am still in confusion how should modify using above script. I tried to add single element in the sub root but it doesn't work for me. Can you help me to modify the same like add, remove and replace element text?

Comment: Chaitanya sama are you there?